# System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file "file location"because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I need to save a file and then read it. But I get the error:

> The Process cannot access the file"

when I debug it.

Also I get this error when I debug through Chrome. However when I debug the same code through IE I get the error:

> The given Path's format is not supported".

Not sure what's going wrong

Controller.cs

```
public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            string fileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/" + postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(fileLocation);
```

`PostedFile.SaveAs(fileLocation)` is the point where the error is thrown.

Comment: How do you attach the file to the request?

Comment: Hi @AlessandroRosá I do that using Angular...

Answer (score 2):

[`posted.FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename?view=netframework-4.8) is the full path on the client machine like *C:\users\myName\Documents\mydoc.pdf*. You are trying to concatenate it to the server *UploadFile* folder and then calling *Server.MapPath* on that resulting string.

This will never work.

You have already extracted the Filename part from the full path. So just use it.

```
string fileLocation = 
   HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/" + fileName);
```

Comment: I corrected that, but the error does not go away.. :-(

Comment: On which line did you get the exception? You could see it on the error message where a fullstack of your code calls is also displayed

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code...

Comment: Sorry, but that's not enough to understand where the error occurs. Look at the details of the exception. You will find the Stack Trace (the path your code has followed to met the exception) and the line of code where the exception happens. Sometime you have also more information looking at the InnerException property of the general Exception received

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(Directory.Exists((fileLocation ))))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory((fileLocation ));
                }
     postedFile.SaveAs(fileLocation);
```

Try this please if error is coming please post the "fileLocation" value what is coming in that Variable.

Comment: Hi @amaldec23 , when I add the above code I get the error "System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot create "path name" because a file or directory with the same name already exists.' "

Comment: string fileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/" + postedFile.FileName); Can you give me file location value coming variable fileLocation  while deubugging after the above step

Comment: Passing a filename to a Directory.CreateDirectory is not correct. And if the Directory exists, CreateDirectory doesn't try to create it, so your check for Exists is not required

Comment: thank you for the help, but the issue is resolved now, I had some processes running in the background that had opened the file, just closed them using Task manager.